# Obfuscating ActionBar code not showing the Menu items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, proguard, menubar

I have developed the application in Android 4.1 version using the ActionBar. If I am not obfuscating the ActionBar code means the menu items are displayed in the ActionBar, while after obfuscating the ActionBar code, the menu items in ActionBar is not at all displayed. The obfuscating code is like the below.

```
-injars       input.jar
-outjars      output.obfuscated.jar
-libraryjars  android.jar
-libraryjars  android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars  annotations.jar 


-dontpreverify
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
            SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keep public class * {
 public protected *;
}

-keepclassmembernames class * {
java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native <methods>;
 }

-keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
static final long serialVersionUID;
private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
java.lang.Object writeReplace();
java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

 -keep public class * extends android.view.View {
  public <init>(android.content.Context);
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
  public void set*(...);
  }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
  }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 }

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
 public void *(android.view.View);
 public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
 public static <fields>;
 }
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; } 
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
```

Is there any procedure to obfuscate the ActionBar code?

EDIT 1:

```
public static void AddMenuItem(String path, int id, String itemLabel)
{ 
    try
    {           
        if(menu!=null)
        {               
        menu.add(0, id, 0, itemLabel).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        MenuItem item=menu.findItem(id);
        InputStream ims = sActiveContext.getAssets().open(path);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);         
        item.setIcon(d); 
        }

    }
    catch(Exception error)
    { 

    }
}
```

I am not using the menu xml resources. I have done add,remove menu items in the action bar by java code only.

Comment: Is this a custom proguard configuration?

Comment: This is the default proguard configuration. I am not customized anything.

Comment: Can you post you menu resource xml so I have class names and methods to work with?

Comment: I have done my add and remove menu items in the action bar by code only. I am not using the menu xml resources. I have updated my question.

Comment: Hmmm well then the link regarding android menu resource does not apply but I noticed that you are using a path for a drawable. What is that path? Why are you not using 'getDrawable(int)' with the resource id?

Comment: The path is nothing but "asset/example.png", which is passed from the javascript. I am developing application for native apps.

Comment: Not sure how javascript applies but why not put the graphic in the 'res/drawables' directory and use getDrawable(R.drawables.example). I think proguard may be removing or altering the filename in the assets directory. Not sure though...

Comment: I am using the library file. resources are not included in the library jar..that's why I preferred the asset folder of the application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30653/discussion-between-larry-mckenzie-and-karthick)

Comment: Is this any way to restrict the proguard, not renaming the file names.?

Comment: Still the menu items are not displayed in the obfuscated jar file. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with a bit of difference. See if it would apply for your case as well or not.

In my `menu_custom.xml` I had an item which had the `actionViewClass`, i.e:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_ad_detailed_share"/>

    <item
        android:actionViewClass="com.example.widget.ActionSeparatorView"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@null"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_favorite_deselected"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_ad_detailed_favorite"/>
</menu>
```

And according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html, if you have any of these attributes:

`android:actionViewClass`
`android:actionProviderClass`
`android:onClick`

You have to exclude the class from being obfuscated:

> Warning: If you obfuscate your code using ProGuard (or a similar tool), be sure to exclude the class you specify in this attribute from renaming, because it can break the functionality.

Meaning that I had to add my widget to `proguard-rules.txt` to fix the problem. i.e:

```
-keep class com.example.widget.ActionSeparatorView { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android recently changed the way they recommend integrating proguard. Try this:

project.properties

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-17
```

proguard-project.txt

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

-keep public class <MyClass>
```

You can find documentation regarding how to notate what you need to keep here:
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

Comment: Hi, this is already there. but still the menu items in ActionBar is not displayed. Shall I do something other than this.?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this is already there. You should adjust you project to work with this new configuration not the old one.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html In this link, if using the proguard have to exclude the menu item class.I have used the menu item functionalities in AddMenu class. How can i exclude the class.?

Comment: Oh I see. I will revise my answer for you.

Comment: If I am using the above code to keep the class, the renaming of the methods are performed are not.? Because, the renaming of the function performed means the menu item functionality have been broken.

Comment: After seeing your comments on your question the menu-resource link does not apply an so this will not likely help you. See my comments on the question regarding the use of getDrawable(R.drawable.example);

Comment: Still the menu items are not displayed in the obfuscated jar file. Any idea?